# jquery-ui,  Choppy dragging into sortable within sortable

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

Im my sample code [here (jsBin)](http://jsbin.com/ehujej/2/edit), i'm having trouble dragging items into the innerSortable smoothly.

Dragging items out of the innerSortable works fine, dragging around within innerSortable works fine, but it's a bit choppy when I try to drag items from the outside sortable to the inner sortable.

looks like a jquery-ui sortable bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try nesting sortables inside other sortables.